# select2 problems with dropdown style and placeholders

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've hit a wall!  My select2 drop boxes (positioned in the middle of each row in the pictures) work beautifully in jsfiddle but when I transfer the exact code to my webpage I get 2 strange issues.  First, the placeholder names start in the 4th dropbox instead of the first one, almost as if there's a margin-top somewhere, which there isn't.

[image: Wrong placeholder locations]

Secondly, the dropdown has become huge and far too spread out.

[image: Over-large dropdown]

Apart from that, all the other styles and jquery work beautifully!  I've spent 2 days on this, looking through all posts, adjusting all the css and html, and nothing. Can anyone offer any ideas?   I'm using version 4.0.3 and include some essential css and jquery below (sorry for the length).

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js

$( function() {

  $("#drop_ingot").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });
  $("#drop_billetbloom").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });
  $("#drop_slab").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });
  $("#drop_rounds").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });
  $("#drop_othersemis").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });  
  $("#drop_rebar").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });
  $("#drop_barrodcoil").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });  
  $("#drop_barflats").select2({ placeholder: "Iron / steel types", });  

// This code ensures the drop menu disappears when deleting a tag.
$('[id^="drop_"]').on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {
    $(this).data('unselecting', true);
  }).on('select2:open', function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('unselecting')) {
      $(this).select2('close').removeData('unselecting');
    }
  });
});




.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #FCFCFC;
border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: text;
height: 24px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 2px 2px 1px;
cursor: pointer;
width:198px;
box-sizing: border-box;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline {
float: left
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
box-sizing: border-box;
background: transparent; 
border: none;
font-size: 100%;
outline: 0;
margin-top: 4px;
padding: 0;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-appearance: textfield
}

.select2-dropdown {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid darkorange;
border-radius: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
position: absolute;
font-family: 'Arial', Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
margin-left: 2px;
z-index: 100;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.select2-results {
display: block;
}

.select2-results__options {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px;
}

.select2-results__option {
padding: 6px;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected] {
cursor: pointer
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
left: 0px;
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
border-top: none;
}

.select2-hidden-accessible {
border: 0 !important;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0) !important;
height: 1px !important;
margin: -1px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
padding: 0 !important;
position: absolute !important;
width: 1px !important;
}

#drop_ptseamless + .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple{
height: auto;
min-height: 24px;
max-height: 45px;
padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
}

#drop_ptwelded + .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple{
  height: auto;
  min-height: 24px;
  max-height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
}

.tagContainerHoverClass:hover {
border: 1px solid darkorange !important;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
box-sizing: border-box;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
width: 100%;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
color: black;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: default;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
padding: 0 6px 0px 3px;
background:    #fff;
background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #dadada);
background:    linear-gradient(#fff, #dadada);
border:        1px solid #878787;
box-shadow:    0 0px 0 0 #666;
text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #f3f3f3;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
color: #5E5E5E;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right: 3px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover {
color: red;
font-size: 105%;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
color: #999;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
color: red!important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
background-color: #CEDDF0;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__group {
cursor: default;
display: block;
padding: 6px
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
display: none;
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
outline:none;
}







<div id="Lower_container_TradeProdsListBoxID_tr" class="Lower_container_TradeProdsListBoxClass_tr">


<div class = "TradeProds_RowProductsTitles">Steel semi-finished products</div>

<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_ingot" value="ingot" />Ingot</label>

<select id="drop_ingot" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
<option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
<option value="Alloy">Alloy</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_ingot_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>



<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_billetbloom" value="billetbloom" />Billet and Bloom</label>

<select id="drop_billetbloom" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
<option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_billetbloom_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>



<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_slab" value="slab" />Slab</label>

<select id="drop_slab" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
<option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_slab_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>



<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_rounds" value="rounds" />Rounds & other semis</label>

<select id="drop_rounds"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_rounds_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>



<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_othersemis" value="othersemis" />Other semis</label>

<select id="drop_othersemis"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
<option value="Alloy">Alloy</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_othersemis_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>



<div class = "TradeProds_RowProductsTitles">Steel Finished Long Products</div>

<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_rebar" value="rebar" />Rebar / debar</label>

<select id="drop_rebar"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_rebar_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>


<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_barrodcoil" value="barrodcoil" />Bar & wire rod (coiled)</label>

<select id="drop_barrodcoil"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
<option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
<option value="Alloy">Alloy</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_barrodcoil_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>



<label><input type="checkbox"  id="tr_barflats" value="barflats" />HR bar & flats</label>

<select id="drop_barflats"  multiple="multiple">
<option value="Carbon">Carbon</option>
<option value="Stainless">Stainless</option>
<option value="Alloy">Alloy</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="TradeProdsPOPUPLink_barflats_ID" class="RHLabelClass" >Trade codes</a>


<!---------------->

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the fiddle or the relevant HTML for the dropdowns? My first instinct is that your overloading of the default CSS is causing some padding to be compounded and pushing everything down by about 3 lines. Either that or the styling of the parent div

Comment: @Whiplash450 much appreciate you looking into this.  Your first instinct could well be right.  I thought that using default CSS was a good thing and hadn't realised it can overload.  I've added some HTML to my post.  you won't thank me for sending the fiddle... it's rather large!

Comment: OK so the html rules out the `<select>` id's mismatching with the select2 initialisers. I'd definitely play around with the CSS. Try taking out all of your custom CSS for the select2's and then adding it back in, a class at a time, and see if the offset builds up or has a single root cause.

Comment: @Whiplash450 you were right all along... it was the CSS.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! This shows the importance of having 'margin: 0px' in the relevant select2 CSS.  I found that:

```
.select2-container .select2-search--inline {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 }
```

solved the placeholder problem, while the dropdown problem was solved with:

```
.select2-results__option {
padding: 5px;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
margin: 0px;
```

}

Previously the 'margin: 0px;' was missing from both of the above.  I think it's something to do with select2 compounding spans in the inbox, and the 'margin: 0px' is needed to cancel this out.  I leave it to those cleverer than me to explain better.  What I still don't understand is why this all worked in jsfiddle but not in my webpage.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it!